# How to get storage location URL of uploaded image on Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase-storage

I have that code which I get download URL:

```
uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(async function(downloadURL) {

});
```

I need also file storage location URL as well.

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by "storage location URL"? Do you want the path to the file in Firebase Storage, like `/files/logo.png`? If you told us what you need it for, it would be easier to help.

Comment: Like that: gs://****.appspot.com/user_avatars/1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `uploadTask.snapshot.ref` is a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference) type object.  The API documentation for that object suggests that the [toString()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#tostring) method will give you a gs:// URL for that reference.